# c++ find() returning a different value when stored as a variable

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I was helping someone with some homework when I came upon something strange.
I don't use C++, but I figured the function find() would work like any other language.
However, in the first example below, an email with the name ericsomthing@gmail.com does not evaluate to false when looking for a space using find(' ').

```
if (classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find(' ') >= 0) // evaluated true even though i dont know why
```

In the second example, find(' ') works but only when stored in a local variable.

```
int test = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find(' ');
if (test >= 0) // evaluates false as expected
```

More verbose example of the code is shown below

Strange broken code:

```
void Tester::printInvalidEmails() {
    NUM_STUDENTS = LAST_INDEX + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; ++i) {
        int test = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find(' ');
        int test1 = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find('@');
        int test2 = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find('.');
        if (classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find(' ') >= 0) {
            cout << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress() << endl;
        }
        if (classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find('@') == -1) {
            cout << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress() << endl;
        }
        if (classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find('.') == -1 ) {
            cout << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But this code works:

```
void Tester::printInvalidEmails() {
    NUM_STUDENTS = LAST_INDEX + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; ++i) {
        int test = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find(' ');
        int test1 = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find('@');
        int test2 = classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find('.');
        if (test >= 0) {
            cout << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress() << endl;
        }
        if (test1 == -1) {
            cout << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress() << endl;
        }
        if (test2  == -1 ) {
            cout << classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does storing the value of find as a local variable 'test' fix the problem?

Comment: In C++, `find(.)` returns an iterator, not a `bool`. Must be compared with `xxx.end()` to check if element exists

Comment: "I figured the function find() would work like any other language" - don't assume behaviour across languages. Different languages are different for a reason and you can never assume that something you learned about one holds true for another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.find(' ') >= 0` is a bad comparison.

I'm guessing you expect that find will return `-1` if it can't find what you're looking for? When you cast the result to an `int` (which you're implicitly doing when you assign it to an `int` variable), it will be `-1`. But the return type of find is actually unsigned, so if you just look at the raw value returned, it can *never* be `< 0` (in other words `.find(' ') >= 0` will always be true).

If you want to check to see if the string actually has a space, use:

```
classRosterArray[i]->GetEmailAddress().find(' ') != std::string::npos
```

For more, take a look at [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). Specifically, from the page on [`npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

> `static const size_type npos = -1;`
>
> Although the definition uses -1, `size_type` is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion. This is a portable way to specify the largest value of any unsigned type.

Comment: so size_type is unsigned but the npos is defined as -1... Then what happens when you have an occurrence in a string that is at the index equal to the largest possible value of unsigned? would that be a collision? I know that a string is typically not that long, just asking to make sure I understand what's going on

Comment: @Goku string size is limited by [`std::string::max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size). Since the return type on that is also `size_type`, it's safe to say that on no system can any `std::string` be that long.

Comment: @Goku: Well, what would happen to your program if a string is so long it takes up all addressable space? ;-) Note that e.g. [`read()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) gets into trouble *much* earlier. (You can specify `size_t` bytes to be read, but the number of bytes read is *returned* as `ssize_t` (sp!)...)

Comment: Thank you all for the help. This was really stressing me out